# excel code to insert data in the first unused column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently writing some routines for the automation of pivot table generation.
In order for the pivot table to work the column I want to insert must be contiguous with the existing data. How do I get Excel to insert that data at the first unused column?

I found the following reference online:

```
Function xlLastCol(Optional WorksheetName As String) As Long

 ' Author:  MWE
 ' http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=418

 '       finds the last populated col in a worksheet

If WorksheetName = vbNullString Then WorksheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
With Worksheets(WorksheetName)
    On Error Resume Next
    xlLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", .Cells(1), xlFormulas, _
    xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
    If Err <> 0 Then xlLastCol = 0
End With

End Function
```

But it always returns some strange number that is definitely NOT the last used column. (First unused column will simply be last used column + 1)

Comment: This code is correct - it does find the last used column looking backwards from cell A1. It will detect a formula, even one evaluating to "", as being a used cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I had posted as according to @brettdj does work. There was somehow a "1" located near the very last column. It may have been there to serve some function in a macro or something but i don't believe it is still used.

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
xlLastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
```

and

```
xlLastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column
```

I havent tested but both should work.

Let me know if you have any problems and i could spend some time testing it myself!

Comment: The first code needs adjusting for the fact that the first used cell may not be in column A, ie `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1).Column + .ActiveSheetUsedRange.Columns.Count`. The second code is the same as the Asker has provided (which already works)

Answer (score 0):

To Get the last available Column in say Row 1 use this code

```
LastCol = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
```